# JavaScript Testing a Simple Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to understand why Jasmine-Node is telling me that `stringCalc` has no method `add` when it's clearly defined. Is add not being attached to the object, or is there something I'm missing as far as requiring the production file?

**Code:**

```
var stringCalc = (function() {
  return {                                                                          
    add: function(string) {                                                                                                                                              
      return 0;
    }
  };
})();
```

**Spec:**

```
var stringCalc = require("../lib/calc");

describe("String Calculator", function() {
  it("should return zero if empty", function() {
    expect(stringCalc.add("")).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping your object in an IIFE?

Comment: Also, please show us your relevant `module.exports` part where you export `calcString` ?

Comment: It's a pattern called the module design pattern. That's all of the code I've written to require the file, I thought this would be a trivial matter. @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: You should not need to wrap things using the module pattern in NodeJS since NodeJS already has built in modules, which you export to using the `exports` object which makes the data available to the outside - which is why there is absolutely no way we can help you unless you show us the `module.exports` part in your code.

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of that. It's strange that replacing ```var stringCalc``` with ```module.exports``` makes the test pass. @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: Not sure if 'strange' is the right word.

Comment: It's not, but It's still a bit fuzzy. Do you think you could provide an explanation in relation to my code. @phenomnomnominal

Comment: You might wanna take a look at the [modules documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to better understand how the `require` function works.  You don't need the IIFE, and can simply define some object (or function) and set it equal to `module.exports`.  Then when you `require` it, you'll get handed what you exported.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this covers a lot of what I was having trouble on. JavaScript has been a pain to learn, but I've enjoyed every minute of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your spec file, the stringCalc variable is redefined to hold whatever has been exported from the calc.js file.  Your code module (the calc file) does not export anything, and so the thing you get by requiring it has no add method.  You can see this by logging the result of the require statement in the test file:

```
var stringCalc = require("./calc");

console.log(stringCalc);
```

which writes this to the console:

```
{}
```

To make things from your code module available, you have to export them.  There are several ways of doing this, such as:

```
exports.add = function(string) {
  return 0;
}
```

With that code, the test passes as you have it written.  If you want to wrap it in a self-executing function so as not to mess up the global scope, you just wrap the whole thing:

```
(function() {

  // private code here; this stuff is not exported
  var s = 'foo';
  var helperFunction = function() { 
    // ...
  }

  exports.add = function(string) {
    return 0;
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Heres' what I did: ```module.exports = function() { ... }``` and included a return on the function add that way anything defined above it would be considered private. Is this still valid?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've done, so I'm not sure.  I'd suggest you look at what console.log(strCalc) does from the spec file, to really understand what it is that you've exported.  If you're happy with that, then it's all good.

Comment: When exported I have an object of ```{ add: [Function] }```. You can see in detail here: http://bit.ly/1hvDHhI